# nav submenu not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, nav

So i am working on a small HP for a school project and am kinda stuck with the nav bar. When i hover over "Gallery" the submenu opens and there's the problem:
I am trying and trying but can't seem to find a way to get the backgroundcolor only for the submenu area and not the whole page on the left of it...

I'm sure it's an easy fix but I am struggling atm

here's the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/67wq84g9

i think it's something here, but if I change the width and hover over the submenu it doesn't completely change color.

```
.menu ul {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you set width for

```
    .menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: #7ebc71;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width:80px;
}
```

and

```
 .menu ul li a:hover {
  background: #557F4C;
  width :80px;
}
```

Comment: ye that solves the problem thanks, but now the border-bottom is too short :/ any idea?

Comment: .menu ul li {
  float: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #557F4C;
  position: relative;
    width:80px;
}

Comment: Set the border width using above code.Let me know if it works for you.